# How to insert a MongoDB document with a timestamp from the database server

Tags: java, mongodb

In Oracle, I could simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable VALUES ('someValue',SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

That would insert two values into myTable, and one of them would be a timestamp based-on the database server's time.

For MongoDB (via the Java driver) I've tried this:

```
myDoc.put("value","someValue");
myDoc.put("timestamp", new Date());
myCollection.insert(myDoc);
```

But that creates a timestamp based-on the client machine's time, not the database server's time.

Is there a way to have MongoDB apply a timestamp to a document based-on the the database server time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A little late to the game - but the recent releases of mongodb have $currentDate.

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/

Comment: what to do if i want to insert a stored date/time value into mongodb in the mongodb-recognised date/timestamp format?

Comment: You can use ISODate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can get the server to generate a Timestamp on insert with `db.test.insertOne( { ts: new Timestamp() } );`. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

Comment: Typescript complains about this `Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.`

Answer (score -1):

Use [Morphia](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/) ORM tool for MongoDB

and for your problem hope lifecycle method of [this](http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/LifecycleMethods) is helpful.

i have getting result by using **@Prepersist** method