# How to insert a document with date in mongo?

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb, mongodb-query

We are trying to insert a document with the current date as it's field. We are writing in java using eclipse plugin for mongodb. We want to execute the `Date()` command of mongo to get the date from mongo and not from java.

How can I execute this mongo query?

```
db.example.insert({"date":new Date()})
```

I found this question in a previews question but the answer was not helpful

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10771439/how-to-insert-a-mongodb-document-with-a-timestamp-from-the-database-server)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to store date/time in mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778428/best-way-to-store-date-time-in-mongodb)

Comment: "eclipse plugin for mongodb" gives many different google hits. Could you narrow it down to a particular product?

Comment: mongo-java-driver-2.12.0-rc2.jar

Comment: This question hasn't been solved yet. I was unable to achieve the same using java using any of the solutions below

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The standard driver takes [java.util.date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) types and serializes as BSON dates. So with a collection object to "example"

```
Date now = new Date();

BasicDBObject timeNow = new BasicDBObject("date", now);
example.insert(timeNow);
```

If you are looking for a way to use the "server" time in operations, there is the [**`$currentDate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate) operator, but this works with "updates", so you would want an "upsert" operation:

```
 BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObect();
 BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$currentDate",
     new BasicDBObject("date", true)
 );

 example.update(query,update,true,false);
```

Since that actually is an update statement, you need to be careful that you are not actually matching any documents if you intend this to be an insert only. So it would be best to make sure your "query" contains unique information, such as a newly generated `_id` or something equally unique.

Comment: This takes the date from the current working machine. Let's say the mongo is running on another server, and there is a small time differential, I want to display the date in the other machine, so I could see the difference even if it's a minute or so

Comment: @Candroid You really should be making sure the times are synchronized, but there is a way to use the server time.

Answer (score 12):

You can do it trying something like this:

```
db.example.insert({"date":ISODate("2016-03-03T08:00:00.000")});
```

Comment: If you write `ISODate()` that field will be the current (on insert) datetime.

Comment: which jar provide the ISODate() class

Comment: @Nicksxs : I think this should be for node.js/shell or someother, but not for java code..

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
db.example.insert({"date":new Date(Date.now())});
```

Comment: I need to write it in java. How can I write this in java eclipse with mongo plugin? I tried using the 'command' but it didn't work

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit?

Comment: The command you wrote is written for mongo shell. I want to execute this command in java language, so my question is how to do it? What is the right syntax?

Comment: Mongo documentation gives the standard way to insert date. http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/insert/

Comment: The documentation does not solve this problem. Has anyone done this in java please

Comment: I think this should be for node.js/shell or someother, but not for java code..

Answer (score 2):

There is a key difference I noted when using Date() as follows.

```
{ dateWhenCreated : Date() }
```

vs

```
{ dateWhenCreated : new Date() }
```

Notice the "new" keyword in the second usage.  Whereas the first usage loads the data "as a string", the second one loads date as a field with date data type.

This might impact your sorting capability - dates stored as strings don't get sorted the same way as dates stored as dates.

Per the mongodb documentation [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/method/Date/)