# MongoDB: add a date using mongoimport with --columnsHaveTypes --headerline

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

I have a `test.tsv` TSV file that has a header looking like this

```
sample.string() organism.string()   capture.string()    sex.string()
```

and I am using the following command to import my file into mongodb

```
mongoimport --quiet -d somedb --collection=somecollection --file=test.tsv --type tsv --mode upsert --upsertFields sample --columnsHaveTypes --headerline
```

I wish to add the [date](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#document-bson-type-date) following mongodb format at the moment of my file import.

I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483727/how-to-insert-a-document-with-date-in-mongo) to do it while in mongodb but I can't seem to find anything about [mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/).

Is there a command (or a workaround) that looks like the following and allows us to add the date of the file content ?

```
mongoimport --quiet -d somedb --collection=somecollection --file=test.tsv --type tsv --mode upsert --upsertFields sample --columnsHaveTypes --headerline --addDate
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround for this:

First, get the date from bash with some formatting:

```
date=$(date -u +"%d-%m-%Y %T")
```

Now, add this variable to all the lines in `file.tsv` like so:

```
awk -v date="$date" '{print $0 "\t" date}' file.tsv
```

Then, we can change the header by adding the date format type

```
$ sed -i '1s/.*/Sample.string()\tOrganism.string()\tCapture.string()\tSex.string()\tDate.date(02-01-2006 15:04:05)/' file.tsv
$ head file.tsv
Sample.string()     Organism.string()     Capture.string()     Sex.string()     Date.date(02-01-2006 15:04:05)
```

Then, we can import with mongoimport:

```
$ mongoimport -d somedb --collection=somecollection --file=file.tsv --type tsv --mode upsert --upsertFields Sample --columnsHaveTypes --headerline
2019-09-30T11:23:37.934+0200    connected to: xxxx
2019-09-30T11:23:37.940+0200    imported 1 document
```

[image: mongocompass]